# Mechanical Turk for Android

Tags: android, image-recognition, mechanicalturk

I’ve recently heard about [Amazon’s Mechanical Turk Service](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) and I would like to incorporate the service into an Android application. Would this be possible? I have heard that other apps such as [MealSnap](http://mealsnap.com/) have used this feature. If yes, where could I find the documentation on how to use it, assuming I have paid for the service and have an account with Amazon?

Also, is it possible to be very specific about what we want the service to return? For example, if I were sending an image with a picture of a laptop, would Mechanical Turk just return that the item is a laptop or will it specify what type of laptop it is and some of its features?

Comment: Mechanical Turk will do what you want it to do, Im not sure how familiar you are with the service but its for the most part actual people performing the tasks. A common example of what people use Mechanical Turk for is the transcribing of voicemails. You can basically ask for anything (within reason) the more things you ask of Mechanical Turk to perform, the more you will have to pay. If you were sending a picture of a laptop, it would obviously be hard to discern much else from the picture other than the brand, HP, Dell, etc.

Comment: I am aware its a HCI service. I was assuming amazon would send the image to specific people. Consider the example of bugs, a nature enthusiast would probably able to identify the exact type of bug. Would that be possible using mechanical turk ?

Comment: Yes, just be prepared to pay accordingly, more more difficult the task is. For something specific like that, you would probably want to Author your own Qualification test so you make sure your getting proper results and the people perform the task exactly how you want them to.

Comment: Someone should have posted a link to this service: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk